# ReSharper Unit Test Runner - TestCase

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I like using the ReSharper unit test runner, but it doesn't support the TestCase attribute that was added in NUnit 2.5. Is there any hack to get round this?

I can obviously use another test runner, but I like the ReSharper one.

Comment: ReSharper v5 full supports nunit 2.5+ and is currently available as a Beta download.

Comment: I've got R# v5.3.1 installed and it seems to be only partial support of the [TestCase(args)] and [TestFixture(args)] ... my tests run, but there is no detail as to which of the test data parameter sets have caused the error

Comment: R# 6.0 has better support for TestCase and TestCaseSources.

Comment: FYI: there is a discussion in the jetbrains resharper forum about this here: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5247736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love ReSharper, but it does not yet support [TestCase].  However, take a look at the Gallio plug-in for ReSharper which does.

http://www.gallio.org/

Comment: I did try Gallio, but didn't get on that well with it. I should probably spend a bit more time with it. I'll probably just wait for Resharper 5 though!

Comment: I can't wait for RS 5 as well.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I use on Resharper version 5 is to use aspects with your tests.  I'd love resharper 6 but upgrading isn't an option for me currently.

You can use PostSharp to create an aspect that does something as simple as simple as printing out the arguments list to the console every time the unit test is run.  When you runt his with the resharper runner in visual studio, if it fails, it will have print out what the arguments were in the output panel. This way you know which test failed.  If you use an aspect you can then re-use this on any test that uses TestCases without having to write your printing statement each time.