# NUnit+ReSharper: How to view results for TestFixture with different parameters?

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

I have written unit tests under NUnit that use TestFixtures with different parameters. Now, when I run tests, I want to see with which parameters test has been passed and with which hasn't. Unfortunately, ReSharper shows only "**Test failed: Child test failed**" and no more information. Is there any way to see which parameters have caused test failure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I e-mailed JetBrains about this and received the following response from Andrey Serebryansky on July 9th, 2010:

> This issue will be addressed in the next ReSharper release.

I believe the current release at the time of this writing is 5.1.

---

### EDIT:

Based on comments by @Damien McGivern and @zcrar70

The issue is [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-147616), and it is fixed in the Resharper internal build.

However according to Victor Kropp (at the above link):

> These changes will NOT be included in 5.1 due to technical reasons.

and when asked what the release date would be the response was (as of August 3, 2010):

> I'm sorry, our roadmap is not yet established. I really don't know.

### EDIT2:

More answers from Victor Kropp:

> Q. Is there any update on a time line for when this will be in a release or nightly build that we can use?
>
> A. ReSharper 6.0 EAP is expected to start before the end of year. I don't know actual date now.
>
> Q. Will this bug fix be available in any release before 6.0?
>
> A. No, sorry.

### EDIT3:

I just tested this with the Resharper 6 EAP (build 2101) and it looks like they did a rather nice job of fixing this issue.

I haven't played around with it too much yet but so far I like what I see.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-179860?query=project:+ReSharper this is the issue in question

The nightly builds for 5.1.1 http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.1.1+Bugfix+Builds as of Aug 3rd don't have it :( so I think we'll have to wait.

Comment: The issue is tracked here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-147616 - the issue is apparently fixed, but no release date is planned currently.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your'e talking about the `TestCaseAttribute`, for a test like this:

```
[TestCase(true, Description = "When true")]
[TestCase(false, Description = "When false")]
[Test]
public void SomeTest(bool parameter) { . . . }
```

I use the Description property for this situation.  With the description property, it will tell you which test case failed.  If you described the situation well enough, it should be self-documenting.

Comment: Tried your solution - still get the same problem. The only thing ReSharper can say is "Test failed: Child test failed". Can you provide simple code and screen shot of ReSharper's Unit Test Session Window output for this test?

Comment: This no longer works for me.  It had worked at some point.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

What version of ReSharper are you using?

**Update:**
I did some research and I don't think the TestCase attribute isn't supported in Resharper 4.X the way you would like it to be.

Apparently it is going to be supported in R# 5.X.

In the mean time there's a PlugIn for ReSharper called [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) that might help.

Got the info from SO question here -> [ReSharper Unit Test Runner - TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479075/resharper-unit-test-runner-testcase)

Comment: I think that you have misunderstood the question. I know how to use asserts etc. The problem is that ReSharper doesn't show which TestCase has failed. It only shows that *one of the* TestCases has failed.

Comment: yep, no probs - thats what I was trying to clarify. So you are wanting Resharper to pickup some Meta data after your tests run. See my new answer re: TestCase attribute and ReSharper

Comment: I'm using ReSharper 5.0 and this feature is not supported there. Hope that JetBrains takes care of this problem and will improve their tests runner in further versions.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how it's failing. In your Assert, the last parameter is an optional string, which you can place fail information in. 
ex: `Assert.IsTrue(false, "Because I'm silly");`

When your test fails, it will have your message right there.

Similarly, you can use Console.Write for test output. There should also be a call stack that describes where the test failed provided you don't catch and waste the exception.

Comment: The issue is with Resharper not displaying which parameterized test fails. Putting an error message in the assert doesn't change that (I did check though.)

Comment: Oh I see. In that case you could always use reflection to spit out the information at run time.. although that is going a bit far >_>