# Is it possible to visualize parametrized NUnit tests using the Resharper GUI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I'm using the [Unit Test Sessions window](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Windows__Unit_Test_Sessions.html) of ReSharper 5.1 in order to run NUnit tests. It gives great visualization and 90% of the time it is just what I need.

[image]

The only problem is that the Unit Test Sessions window does not support tests that have parameters. I would like to have a separate node for each value of the parameters, like in [the screenshots here](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/08/taking-look-at-nunit-25-alpha-3.html). In ReSharper I only see one node for the whole method, and there is no way to know which parameters it passed with and which parameters it failed with.

Is there any way that I can see the various runs in ReSharper, or do I need a different tool (and which one is the best)?

Thank you!

Comment: Ping the @resharper team and try and get it in v6.0!

Comment: Please feel free to submit a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The feature which you are requesting will be part of Resharper 6. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-147616.

In the meantime you could try to use [gallio](http://www.gallio.org) as stated here [ReSharper Unit Test Runner - TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479075/resharper-unit-test-runner-testcase)

---

As ReSharper 6 is now available you could find information about its TestCase support here http://hadihariri.com/2011/08/23/new-features-in-resharper-6-unit-test-runner/

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at it! And I'm so sorry, I really wanted to give you the bounty, but then I discovered it has run out - I probably came home a few hours too late.

Comment: As long as my answer was helpful, everything is fine ;)

Comment: Perhaps you might have missed out on the bounty, but here's a +10 for your nice attitude :) Also, my vote put you over 1k, so congrats!

Answer (score 0):

The feature you need does not exist in v5.x of the product as far as I know.

Comment: So what other product should I use?